# How to get a list of keys of a map in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to get a list of keys of a map in dart programming language.

I am familiar with dictionary in python and for the same objective in python there exists a direct method.
I fail to find this in dart.

Is their any work around ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```dart
void main() { 
   var details = {'Usrname':'tom','Password':'pass@123'}; 
   print(details.keys); \\ Gives an Iterable<String>.

   \\ And to return a true List:
   List newList = details.keys.toList();
}
```

`(Usrname, Password)`

Comment: That's not a list, that's an Iterable<String>

Comment: then just call toList() on the Iterable. https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.1/dart-core/Iterable/toList.html